# c# appendformat changes value for backslash

Tags: c#, jquery

i am creating a jquery script in c# to populate on the page. One of my field id's has a period, so i need to place a \ before the period so the jquery will work. When i use the appendformat it removes one of the backslash:

```
s.AppendFormat("\t\t\t\t $(\'#{0}\').show();", "test\\.test");
```

expected result:

```
$('#test\\.test').show();
```

Comment: There is no backtick in you code, did you meant backslash? What do you expect the output to be? `$('#test\.test').show();` this is what I obtained. Backslash is a escape character, if you want two, you have to escape them like `"test\\\\.test"` or use a literal string `@"test\\.test"`

Comment: yes sorry i meant backslash. and i want it to display$('#test\\.test').show(); the \\\\ worked. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two levels of escaping to consider. The first is C# literals (which is what's causing `\t` to produce a tab character), and the second is JavaScript. Both languages escape the backslash with a preceding backslash, so to end up with two backslashes in your JavaScript you need to have four backslashes in your C# string:

```
"test\\\\.test"
```

Or, alternatively, use a verbatim string, which doesn't use backslashes for escape characters:

```
@"test\\.test"
```